# If $D\colon A\to A$ is a locally nilpotent derivation, then $Q(A)^D=Q(A^D)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra which is a domain over some field $k$ of characteristic zero, and $D:A\to A$ be a locally nilpotent derivation on $A$. That is, $D$ is $k$-linear and obeys

$$D(fg)=D(f)g+fD(g)$$

for all $f,g\in A$. Furthermore, for every $f\in A$ there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $D^n(f)=0$.

We can extend $D$ to a (not necessarily locally nilpotent) derivation on the quotient field $Q(A)$ via

$$D:Q(A)\to Q(A),\quad\frac{f}{g}\mapsto\frac{D(f)g-fD(g)}{g^2}.$$

I don't understand why we have that $Q(A^D)=Q(A)^D$, where the exponent $D$ means that we consider the kernel of $D$ in the respective algebra. The inclusion $Q(A^D)\subseteq Q(A)^D$ is obvious though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $Q(A^D)\supseteq Q(A)^D$, let $0 \neq\frac{f}{g}\in Q(A)^D$.

We'd like to show
$f, g \in A^D$.

Since $D$ is locally nilpotent, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $D^n(f)=0$, but $D^{n-1}(f)\neq0$. Similarly there exists such $m$ for $g$. Assume $f$ and $g$ are such that $\max(n,m)$ is minimal.

Now
$$ \frac{f}{g}\in Q(A)^D \implies D\Big(\frac{f}{g}\Big)=0 \implies \frac{D(f)g-fD(g)}{g^2} =0 \implies D(f)g-fD(g) =0.
$$

Note that $D(f)=0 \iff D(g)=0$. If this is the case, i.e. if $D(f)=D(g)=0$, we're done.

Suppose that $D(f),D(g) \neq 0$. Then
$$ \frac{D(f)}{D(g)} = \frac{f}{g} \in Q(A)^D,$$
contradicting the assumed minimality.